# Chart Js flickering or switching as i move mouse on canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a chart on my page using ChartJs and then i placed three buttons so that when clicked, it represents the data in a different chart type. 
but the issue i am having is that if i move the mouse pointer across the canvas after switching to a different graph, it keeps switching or flickering and this is not good, how can i get it to stay on the current chart type.

i tried clearing the canvas and context object before rendering the chart but yet, it still refuses to work, here's my code..

```
var chartx;
var cv;


var mnts, vals, mx, steps; // for the chart labels..
```

//retrieve the json data from this url.. 
    var setting = {
       type:'GET',
       url:'/ajax/stats/summary'
    };

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';  

  cv = document.getElementById('dboard');  //the canvas object
  pullChartData('line');                  //draw the line graph first

});

function pullChartData(chtype){

   shwChldx();     //show the GIF loader 
   clearCanvas();  //clear the canvas

   $.ajax(setting)
    .done(function(response){       
       o = JSON.parse(response);

       mnts = String(o.days).split(';');   //array of horizontal labels
       vals = String(o.values).split(';'); //array of values
       mx = Number(o.mx);                  //maximum value among chart data
       steps = Number(o.step);             //get the step to use on chart

       setChartType(chtype);
       hideChldx()

    }).fail(function(xhr,status,error){

       hideChldx();
       notifyCVS('error loading CHART data...');

    });
}


function shwChldx(){   //show loader GIF 
  $('#tkldr').css('display', 'block');
}


function hideChldx(){     //hide loader GIF
  $('#tkldr').css('display', 'none');
}


function drawChart(cdiv, ctype){  //draw graph function

    chartx = new Chart(cdiv, {
                    type: ctype,
                    data: {
                      labels: mnts,     
                      datasets: [{
                        data: vals,
                        label: ' - visits at on this day',
                        borderColor: '#324463',
                        fillColor: 'rgba(109,177,117,0.71)',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        fill: true
                      }]
                    },

                    options: {

                          backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                          titleFontSize: 16,
                          titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
                          titleMarginBottom: 10,
                          bodyFontColor: '#000',
                          bodyFontSize: 12,
                          displayColors: false,
                          xPadding:10,
                          yPadding:10,

                      },

                      legend: {
                        display: false,
                          labels: {
                            display: false
                          }
                      },
                      scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            max: mx,
                            stepSize: Number(steps),
                          }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true,
                            fontSize: 11
                          }
                        }]
                      }
                    }
               });

          }
//clear the canvas object before anything.. 
function clearCanvas(){
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
  notifyCVS('retrieving data, please wait...');
}

   //this is the function referenced on the buttons.. 
   //example - <button onclick="setChartType('bar')"></button> 
   // and i have 3 buttons for 'line', 'bar', 'horizontalBar' types

function setChartType(type){
  clearCanvas();
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
  drawChart(cv, type);
}

//i call this function to write on the canvas when there is 
//no activity so that its not just a blank white object..

function notifyCVS(txt){
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#777777";
  ctx.font = "Regular 12px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(String(txt), (cv.width / 2) - 17, (cv.height / 2) + 8);
}
```

so this is my approach, the chart and everything works, but after clicking the different buttons the behaviour changes on mousemove and i dont know where the problem is from, thats just the problem, the flickering behaviour.

please what should i do.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to literally clear the canvas. But you need to **destroy** the chartjs object before you reinitialize it. So, it's like re-creating a chartjs object on the same canvas.
All you need to do is check if the instance already exists before creating the object in drawChart method.

```
function drawChart(cdiv, ctype){
      if(chartx){
            chartx.destroy();
      }
      chartx = new Chart(.....
      ...... 
}
```